# Mediagallery images not corresponding with Sku images

Tags: product, media, gallery

I'm trying to get all the the different kind of product images from the Media-gallery (see code below). Product with the `black-11` SKU is my black-product but it doesn't show that product image. What is wrong with the code. I noticed this with all the product so maybe it's a sorting problem or initiating

```
<?php
require '../app/Mage.php';
Mage::app("default");

$gallery_images = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('black-11')->getMediaGalleryImages();

$items = array();

foreach($gallery_images as $g_image) {
  echo "URL: " . $g_image['url'] . "<br/>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `load` method accepts numeric ID's only.
Try the following

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('black-11', 'sku')[....]
```

or

```
$productId = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku('black-11');
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId)[....]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong with your code `->load('black-11')`.
The `load` method takes as parameter the PK of the entity you are trying to retrieve.
Use `->load('black-11', 'sku')` instead.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know:

`->load()` expects an ID while you using an SKU.

So please try:

`->loadbysku('your-sku')` or `->loadbyattribute('sku','your-sku')`